How can I scope a binding for an external class with an Inject constructor?
Say I have class Foo living in some external module I can’t modify. It had an @Inject constructor. All of the dependencies of Foo are specified in my module, so it injects just fine, just unscoped. I want to effectively @Binds this class to itself, but with a scope. Is there a clean way to do this? I can use a scoped @Provides and take all the arguments and just invoke the constructor directly, but I’m wondering if there’s a cleaner way.
